# Why am I being prompted to enter a password to my Chrome Remote Desktop when I did not create one?

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, virtualization, remote-desktop

I just set up Chrome Remote Desktop for my GCE virtual machine. I followed this tutorial to set it up https://ubuntu.com/blog/launch-ubuntu-desktop-on-google-cloud, and disabled authentication according to the tutorial, however every time I am idle for even a minute I am prompted to enter a password that I do not have. I have tried entering the PIN I created during set up, but to no avail. The only thing that works is restarting it VM, and then a couple of minutes later it's back to the same problem. I have searched and searched online for a solution, but I haven't found anyone with my exact problem.

[image: screenshot of my screen]

Comment: did you try just pressing "enter"?

Comment: I did, and it just says "Sorry that didn't work. Please try again".

Comment: The image you have seems to indicate that the passwd prompt is by gnome not crd.

Answer (score 1):

According to the google cloud document that I found. After you have created vm and remote desktop, you need to set a new password for the user as well. Just simply `sudo passwd $(whoami)` and you can use your new password for the remote desktop.
Here's the link that I found the solution
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#xfce

Hope this can help you